# Problema al establecer rps Jmeter

Tags: test, rendimiento, timer, jmeter

Tengo un problema y es que tengo que hacer un test de carga donde tengo los rps, el problema viene cuando le pongo un "throughput shaping timer" para controlar los hps que no me lo hace correctamente o un "constant throughput timer" y me sigue sin hacer caso al hacer los rps, por mas que pongo nunca consigo hacer la marca que necesito tanto porque se pasa como porque se queda corta.
Alguien podria hecharme un cable o almenos explicar como controlar los rps.

Gracias.